# How to make smooth spline interpolation setting derivatives only at specific points, in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, interpolation, spline

## TL;DR

Apparently `scipy` doesn't provide a method similar to MATLAB's `spapi` that allows for setting the derivatives only at specific points, **ensuring smooth transitions** all along the interpolated spline. I'd like to find a way to do that in Python.

## Overall

My goal is to make spline interpolation using Python 3, but setting the desired derivatives only at specific points. For example, say the array X defines position of an object, point to point, I'd want a spline to represent a feasible trajectory, but also ensuring that the speed (first derivative) is zero at both starting and ending points, other points having no constraints on the derivatives. In this example, I could also desire to have the acceleration (second derivative) equal to zero at the same points.

What I want is, in other words, an implementation of spline interpolation similar to the MATLAB's `spapi` function, as referenced [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/spapi.html):

> `spline = spapi(knots,x,y)` returns the spline *f* (if any) of order
>
> `k = length(knots) - length(x)`
>
> with knot sequence knots for which
>
> `(*)   f(x(j)) = y(:,j), all j.`
>
> If some of the entries of `x` are the same, then this is taken in the **osculatory sense**, i.e., in the sense that `Dm(j)f(x(j)) = y(:, j)`, with `m(j) : = #{ i < j : x(i) = x(j) }`, and `Dmf` the `mth` derivative of *f*. Thus r-fold repetition of a site `z` in `x` corresponds to the prescribing of value and the first `r – 1` derivatives of *f* at `z`.

## What I've tried

I know of the method `from_derivatives` of the `BPoly` class of `scipy.interpolate`, but that poses a critical problem, being that when derivatives are not specified at any point, the algorithm does not guarantee smooth transition, as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60036280/12818877). I also tried what was proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48026686/12818877), but as expected, the same problem arises.

So, next I present simple reproductions of what I'm trying to achieve, successful or not.

### `spapi` without derivatives

Here, example using `spapi` method, in MATLAB, **without** setting any derivatives. Not as what I want since the derivatives are high at start and end points:

```matlab
xi = linspace(0, 10, 6);
xnew = linspace(0, 10, 100);

yi = [0 2 1 4 2 0];

knots = optknt(xi, order);
ref_spline = spapi(knots, xi, yi);

spline = fnval(xnew, ref_spline);
der_spline = gradient(spline);
```

And the corresponding plot of reference points along with the interpolated spline:
[image: Spline interpolation without setting derivatives, using <code>spapi</code>]

And here the 1st order derivative of that spline:
[image: 1st derivative of the interpolated spline]

### `spapi` with derivatives

Here, example using `spapi` method, in MATLAB, **setting derivatives as `0`** at both start and end points. Exactly the expected result, with smooth transitions all along the spline, and derivatives equal to `0` at start and end points:

```matlab
xi = linspace(0, 10, 6);
xnew = linspace(0, 10, 100);
xder = [0 xi 10];

yi = [0 2 1 4 2 0];
ynew = [0 yi 0];

knots = optknt(xder, order);
ref_spline = spapi(knots, xder, ynew);

spline = fnval(xnew, ref_spline);
der_spline = gradient(spline);
```

And the plot of reference points along with the spline:
[image: Spline interpolation setting derivatives as zero at start and end, using <code>spapi</code>]

And here the 1st order derivative of that spline:
[image: 1st derivative of the interpolated spline]

### `BPoly.from_derivatives` with derivatives

Here, example using `BPoly.from_derivatives` **setting derivatives as `0`** at both start and end points. Unsuccessful, even though the derivatives are `0` at start and end, smooth transition is not guaranteed along the spline:

```py
ref_points = [0, 2, 1, 4, 2, 0]
time_vector = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
time_points = np.linspace(0, 10, 6)

ref_complete = [[ref_points[j] if (i == 0) else 0 for i in range(2)] if (
    (j == 0) or (j == len(ref_points) - 1)) else [ref_points[j]] for j in range(len(ref_points))]

ref_spline = BPoly.from_derivatives(time_points, ref_complete)
spline = ref_spline(time_vector)

der_spline = ref_spline.derivative(1)
der_y = der_spline(time_vector)
```

To clarify, the line that defines `ref_complete` simply replaces the first and last elements of `ref_points` by an array containing the original value at index `0`, and a `0` at index `1`:

```py
>>> ref_points
[0, 2, 1, 4, 2, 0]
>>> ref_complete
[[0, 0], [2], [1], [4], [2], [0, 0]]
```

And the plot of reference points along with the spline:
[image: Spline interpolation setting derivatives as zero at start and end, using <code>BPoly.from_derivatives</code>]

And here the 1st order derivative of that spline:
[image: 1st derivative of the interpolated spline]

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to do cubic spline interpolation with zero derivatives at both ends this is enough ([docs here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.html))

```
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline

CubicSpline(time_points, ref_points, bc_type="clamped")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but, actually, I'd like to be able to choose the order of the spline, because for the main use the cubic spline doesn't suit well. Also, not strictly needed but desired, would be nice to be able to set derivatives at any point, not only first and last, and not necessarily zero.